<solved> DataGridView linked to a BindingList : sorting rows not working
I am a beginner.
I am developing a program in C# with Visual Studio and Forms. My Form has a DataGridView linked to a BindingList. I would like to be able to sort rows by clicking a column header.
I set the SortMode to Automatic, but it doesn't work : there's no glyph in the column header and clicking on it won't sort the rows.
Here is my code :
public class SimpleTask
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}

//Code in my Form :
BindingSource tasksBinding = new BindingSource();

//uiTaskGridView is the name of my DataGridView
uiTaskGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

//add one column
var taskNameColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    DataPropertyName = "Title",
    HeaderText = "Titre",
    Width = 300,
    Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False,
    SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic
};
uiTaskGridView.Columns.Add(taskNameColumn);

//create bindinglist and populate
var bindingList = new BindingList<SimpleTask>();
bindingList.Add(new SimpleTask { Title = "Complete project", CategoryName = "Work" });
bindingList.Add(new SimpleTask { Title = "Buy groceries", CategoryName = "Personal" });

tasksBinding.DataSource = bindingList;

uiTaskGridView.DataSource = tasksBinding;


Result is :

Anybody can tell me why I can't sort the "Title" column?
Thanks a lot.

I hadn't searched enough in stackoverflow but browsing more deeply in the Q&A, I found the answer : my data are stored in a List<>, which does not support sorting. I tried a BindingList<> but it does not work either.
Finally, I managed to find a SortableBindingList<> implementation that does support sorting and it works fine! I just replaced "var bindingList = new BindingList();" with "var bindingList = new SortableBindingList();".
Here is the code for the SortableBindingList<> :
   public class SortableBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    private bool isSorted;
    private ListSortDirection sortDirection;
    private PropertyDescriptor sortProperty;

    // Constructeur sans paramètres
    public SortableBindingList() : base() { }

    // Constructeur qui accepte une liste
    public SortableBindingList(IList<T> list) : base(list) { }

    protected override bool SupportsSortingCore => true;

    protected override bool IsSortedCore => isSorted;

    protected override ListSortDirection SortDirectionCore => sortDirection;

    protected override PropertyDescriptor SortPropertyCore => sortProperty;

    protected override void ApplySortCore(PropertyDescriptor prop, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        var items = (List<T>)Items;
        var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(prop.Name);

        if (propertyInfo != null)
        {
            items.Sort((x, y) =>
            {
                var valueX = propertyInfo.GetValue(x);
                var valueY = propertyInfo.GetValue(y);
                return direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending
                    ? Comparer<object>.Default.Compare(valueX, valueY)
                    : Comparer<object>.Default.Compare(valueY, valueX);
            });
            isSorted = true;
            sortProperty = prop;
            sortDirection = direction;
        }
        else
        {
            isSorted = false;
        }

        // Raise the ListChanged event so bound controls refresh their data.
        OnListChanged(new ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1));
    }

    protected override void RemoveSortCore()
    {
        isSorted = false;
        sortProperty = null;
        sortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
    }
}

